# Misspelling "argc" as "argv" results in a comparison between a char ** and an int - why?

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

For the sake of simplicity, take this bit of useless code. If I try and compile the below snippet of code using clang, I get the follow error message:
    argc_test.c:5:14: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('char **' and 'int') [-Werror] if (argc != 4)

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int agrc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc != 4){
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect usage."); 
    }
}
```

I know that the error is caused by the typo on line 5 (declaring the variable "agrc" instead of "argc". What I want to know is why does this result in the comparison of a char ** and an int in the if statement? Does this mean that argc is a char **, even though I haven't declared it?

That wasn't the only error message I got, it's just the one that stood out. Here's the full command line output:

```
~/workspace/week_4/pset_4/resize/ $ make argc_test

clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    argc_test.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o argc_test

argc_test.c:5:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'argc'; did you mean 'argv'?
    if (argc != 4){
        ^~~~
        argv
argc_test.c:4:26: note: 'argv' declared here
int main(int agrc, char *argv[]){
                         ^
argc_test.c:5:14: error: comparison between pointer and integer ('char **' and 'int') [-Werror]
    if (argc != 4){
        ~~~~ ^  ~
argc_test.c:4:14: error: unused parameter 'agrc' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int agrc, char *argv[]){
             ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [argc_test] Error 1
```

Comment: only the first error matters. The other messages are bogus because the compiler makes some invalid guesses to try and move past the first error

Comment: When it asks if I meant 'argv', is that its way of saying its assumed that is what I meant, treated it as such and encountered an error? Analogous to when google reinterprets a typo and provides search results assuming you  meant something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `argc` is auto-corrected to `argv` when clang encounters the error

```
argc_test.c:5:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'argc'; did you mean 'argv'?
```

And of course if you compare `argv` to `4`, you are comparing a pointer to an integer.

This kind of auto-correction is called "fix-it hints", see https://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html.

Comment: There  is no "auto-corrected", the names are arbitrary, it is the actual definition if the arguments in the called function, `main` in this instance, that matters,

Answer (score 0):

int main(int agrc, char *argv[])

An error declaring ARGC integer - you called it AGRC.
I suppose thats why clang doesnt understands it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm aware of the typo, I pointed it out in the original post. I wanted to know how a typo resulted in the comparison between an integer and a char **.